# clearInterval not working electron on ARM

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

In the following code snippet the clearInterval command is not working. The setInterval integer reports to be 14. I am running this on an Orange Pi One (ARM) board running electron.js

```html
  <div class="centre_screen" id="success_frame">
    <p class="white_text" id="success_text_1">Payment successful!</p>
    <button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
    <img src="img/tick.png" id="tick_img" />
    <p class="white_text" id="success_text_2">Your locker will now power on</p>
    <br>
    <p class="white_text" id="success_text_3">Thank you for using Locker services</p>
    <progress value="0" max="10" id="progressBar"></progress>
  </div>

  <script>
```

```js
    var interval = setInterval(prog_bar,2000);

    function prog_bar()
    {
      console.log(String(interval));
      return;
    }

    function stop()
    {
      console.log("STOP: " + String(interval));
      clearInterval(interval);

    }
```

Comment: It's unclear what is not working. What is the exact behaviour you're getting and what is the desired behaviour?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, the setInterval runs as expected but does not stop when the stop button is pressed. It seems clearInterval isnt stopping the setInterval

Comment: *What is the exact behaviour you're getting*? Which of console.log output appear? *The setInterval integer reports to be 14* - this detail is misleading. It doesn't matter what `interval` is but it's unclear what why you pay attention to it. From the question, it currently looks like that you deduced that `clearInterval` doesn't work because `interval` is 14 but this is wrong conclusion.

Comment: My conclusion is that clearInterval is not working because 14 is continually being printed to console (every 2000mS) after pressing the stop button. I pay attention to it just to check it is accessible in both functions. I could equally just log a string ie "HERE" its only for test

Comment: Do you get `STOP` in output? If you don't, that's the problem. There's no https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve in the question, there are two snippets that aren't related. There could be no `stop()` function in global scope.

Comment: Yes I do get STOP in console but the logging of 14 from the setInterval function continues. Surely the HTML is required as it demonstrates how I'm calling the stop function?

Comment: Then it looks like a bug, I'd suggest to report it in Electron repo with all necessary details to reproduce it.